# Not able to reconnect using bluetoothgatt.connect() + android ble

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

We are writing a ble application where want to have a persistent connection with the peripheral we want to connect. For the same purpose we want to re-connect with the peripheral whenever we loose a existing connection. So android application as a central just tries to reconnect using bluetoothgatt.connect() method.

But whenever we try to do that our reconnection gets failed with

12-02 21:47:11.865: D/BluetoothGatt(31963): onClientConnectionState() - status=6 clientIf=6 device=******** callback.

The strange thing here is status=6 which is request not supported.

Initially we get connected to the peripheral with bluetoothdevice.connectGatt method with or without autoconnect flag set.

Another thing we observe is that originally when we are loosing connection we are getting following callback

onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=6 device=******** callback. Where status 8 is GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION. But if you see the btsnoop_hci.log file the reason for disconnection is connection timeout which is expected because we went out of range. But status=8 is misleading.

Another thing we found not obvious is that if I discard the existing bluetoothgatt object after disconnection and just create a new one using bluetoothdevice.connectGatt we get connected to the device which is more weird.

We are observing all these things on nexus 5 with lollipop and few other devices.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

First you all status 8, for timeout is not at all misleading. Because that is what you get when there is actually a connection timeout because of any reason, like your peripheral got switched off or it moved out of the range.

Secondly you would receive status - 6 (not supported request) mostly because the first request of yours is auto connect request (i.e. you passed true in connectGatt method for auto flag) where android ble implementation will take the responsibility to get you connected whenever you get timeout. That means you do not have to make a connection request again as you will get connected automatically whenever peripheral come back in range.

Comment: I would say `GATT_INSUF_AUTHORIZATION` is a misleading error code when the actual problem is a connection timeout. Actually I wouldn't say misleading, I would say totally incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

I would like help you just i need more information about the disconnection side device.
When you lose the connection, the device is always on?

I think you need to do an another scan, whether the device is again on, for init Android with the spécifique device.
When your run the scan, Android saves some information of the device and use their information in connection with him.

You can try rescan the device with BluetoothAdapter.startLeScan() and after you have get the device you can use bluetoothdevice.connectGatt().

Tell me if it work.

Regards